# How can I build a "top 100 list" of influential Twitter users in various categories?

Tags: twitter, list

Can someone please tell me how I could get a list of the top 100 tweets for a selected category, something like this http://www.easyweddingsearch.com/m/top100tweeters.php

Answer (score 2):

A "top 100" Twitter list will always be highly subjective. 
What makes them the top: Number of followers? Actually being an expert? Number of RT's?

Here are some sources to try and get your data:

- Search: "Top twitter [topic]"
- [Klout.com](http://klout.com) - When you sign in you can search for users influential in a general topic.
- [listorious.com](http://listorious.com/) - Twitter user search and directory.
- [WeFollow.com](http://wefollow.com) - Outdated, but still a good reference.
- Twitter lists from other top users in a category.